# Generating Jekyll Pages from Liquid and Markdown instead of HTML

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm using a slightly modified version of the example generator from [Jekyll's plugins section](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Plugins#generators) and I'm curious to know if there is any way to parse a liquid/markdown file instead of a plain HTML files from the example?

Notice this line:

```
self.read_yaml(File.join(base, '_layouts'), 'category_index.html')
```

That category `index.html` file is the target file which will be used in generated files. My goal is to be able to pass an object to a my generator from my `_config` file which I can then use to build a bunch of pages from a `.markdown` file instead.

How can I achieve this? I looked into the Kramdown lib that's used to parse markdown internally, and I'm not opposed to invoking it myself if I have to, just wasn't sure if I was going deeper than I needed to for something that should be so simple. The API for the Page object which my generator creates is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/j/jekyll-0.12.0/Jekyll/Page.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate virtually any format you want, from virtually any data source you want, in a generator, because you're writing straight Ruby with full access to the Jekyll object model. For example, here's a generator I put together the other night that [fetches GitHub commits during `jekyll build`](https://github.com/codingthewheel/codingthewheel.com/blob/master/jekyll/app/_plugins/jekyll-fetch-github.rb).

The question I would be asking is this:

1. Do I need a plugin to accomplish this?
2. If so, do I need a formal generator plugin as discussed in the [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/)?
3. Or should I subclass, monkey-patch, or otherwise change the behavior of the built-in generator?

Also, the differences between Markdown and HTML files in this context (where you control 100% of what gets generated) are mostly nominal. `read_yaml` IIRC will actually read the front matter from both, so that shouldn't be an issue.